# Replace all keys and manipulate values in a python dict and construct a new dict in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, data-manipulation

## Dict to manipulate

```
     data =  {
          "homepage.services.service_title_1": "Web Development",
          "homepage.services.service_title_2": "App Development"
      }
```

The goal is to replace all data's keys with "key" and add new "content" keys having the value of the previous/original dict(data dict) and for each key replaced, push a new dict(with "key" prop and "content" prop) to a list as below.

## Expected Output

```
    texts = [{
    "key": "homepage.services.service_title_1",
    "content": "Web Development"
    },
    {
    "key": "homepage.services.service_title_2",
    "content": "App Development"
     }]
```

Comment: Show us what code you have so far and we will help you. If you want someone to write it for you then you will have to pay ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in this way:

```
data =  {
          "homepage.services.service_title_1": "Web Development",
          "homepage.services.service_title_2": "App Development"
      }

texts = []
for i,j in data.items():
    new_obj = {}
    new_obj["key"] = i
    new_obj["content"] = j
    texts.append(new_obj)
    
print(texts)
```

If the data is in list of dicts form, use this method

```
data =  [{
          "homepage.services.service_title_1": "Web Development",
          "homepage.services.service_title_2": "App Development"
      },{
          "homepage.services.service_title_1": "Mobile Development",
          "homepage.services.service_title_2": "Tab Development"
      }]

texts = []
for item in data:
    for i,j in item.items():
        new_obj = {}
        new_obj["key"] = i
        new_obj["content"] = j
        texts.append(new_obj)
    
print(texts)
```

Comment: what if the "data"  dict was a list of dicts?

Comment: Use one more `for` loop to iterate over the list of dicts

Comment: Already did before I asked. Seemed to be running infinitely

Comment: Once update the list of dicts you have in the question